# Activate Akismet on installation with akismet key

Tags: akismet

I want Akismet to be activated by default on installation with my Akismet API key. I am making my own distribution that I will use on my own sites and I want the plugin and key to already be activated when installing a new wordpress site.

Comment: take a look at this  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/how-to-activate-plugins-via-code

Comment: How would you be providing the key? Are you trying to dynamically get an API Key that is used in the install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link *Bainternet* provides looks quite promising. Now you only need to automatticaly add the API key. Akismet has a constant for this called *WPCOM_API_KEY* ([source code](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/akismet/trunk/akismet.php)).

So you could add something like this to your wp-config.php file and Akismet would use it as API key.

```
define( 'WPCOM_API_KEY', 'abcd1234efgh' );
```