# Activate a plugin via a SQL query

Tags: plugins, activation

I am looking for a way to activate a plugin via a SQL query. I am aware you can login and hit "activate" on the particular plugin, but I would like to automate the activation as part of a release process.

I came across 
[this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/how-to-activate-plugins-via-code) which makes me think that it may not be possible as the activate plugins are stored in `wp_options` in a specific format.

I am using a heavily-modified version of WordPress 3.3.1.

Comment: What _specific format_ are you talking about? The data has been [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), that's it.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is *automated plugin activation* you don't have to do it via SQL. You could, of course, but why not use functionality that comes with WordPress?

As I mentioned in my comment, the data has been serialized so you just have to

- unserialize the data,
- add your plugin,
- re-serialize the data,
- and update the option.

Here is a code snippet for that:

```
$active_plugins = unserialize(get_option('active_plugins'));
if ($active_plugins && is_array($active_plugins)) {
    $active_plugins[] = 'PLUGIN-DIR/PLUGIN-FILE.php'; // as in 'akismet/akismet.php'
    update_option('active_plugins', serialize($active_plugins));
} else {
    // something went wrong...
}
```

Comment: How does your solution help to figure out `a way to activate a WordPress plugin via a SQL query.`?

Comment: @EugeneManuilov It does not. However, despite the title reads _activate ... via SQL_, the question itself asks for an _automated plugin activation_ - and that is exactly what my answer provides... That being said, you're right in that I could/should indicate this in my answer.

Comment: that's better now ;)