# Get access to Wordpress when logged out

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

I have a WP site with bbPress installed and bbPress Like Button (a like button plugin).

I was trying to import a phpBB forum to bbPress.

I'm having problems doing this and in the process must have decactivted bbPress.

Now when I try to log in at wp-admin or view the site I get a page saying.

'bbPress Like Button needs bbPress installed and activated in order to work.'

This is on QA server and so I can't get access to the files.

Is there any way to fix this - Is there any way to access the dashboard to re-activate the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the plugin mishaps are blocking you from signing into the dash? You will likely need server access or someone who has this access if you're not using version control.

You can just rename the folder for the plugin that you want to de-activate (BBPress Like Button). That will force it to de-activate since the WordPress will lose track of it. Then log into the dashboard, activate the appropriate plugin (BBPress) and then return the plugin folder (BBPress Like Button) back to what it was before you changed it. Then you can activate BBPress Like Button once you're sure it has what it needs and won't break your admin access.

This question might also be helpful for you, see Rarst's answer: [How To Activate Plugins via Code?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/how-to-activate-plugins-via-code)