# Activate plugins by a theme's functions.php?

Tags: plugins, themes, activation

Is it possible to activate plugins per theme?

I have a multisite, and I know it is possible to activate plugins per site. But I need plugins to be enabled for specific themes.

Someone asked a similar question - if it is possible to activate plugins by other plugins: [How To Activate Plugins via Code?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/how-to-activate-plugins-via-code)

This was an accepted answer:

```
    //Activate a plugin programmatically - Akismet example

    function run_activate_plugin( $plugin ) {
    $current = get_option( 'active_plugins' );
    $plugin = plugin_basename( trim( $plugin ) );

    if ( !in_array( $plugin, $current ) ) {
        $current[] = $plugin;
        sort( $current );
        do_action( 'activate_plugin', trim( $plugin ) );
        update_option( 'active_plugins', $current );
        do_action( 'activate_' . trim( $plugin ) );
        do_action( 'activated_plugin', trim( $plugin) );
    }

    return null;
}
run_activate_plugin( 'akismet/akismet.php' );
```

However someone commented about this not being very safe and I'm also not sure if this would be a good idea to add to a theme's functions.php file.

I added this above code to a themes functions.php to activate some plugins and so far this is working without any problems. Would I run into problems with this, or is there some better code to use? There is also this function `activate_plugin()` not sure if that function is a better way to activate plugins.

I am no good with code, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, [activate_plugin()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/activate_plugin/) can be used to activate plugins for a specific theme. In the example below, I am using [after_setup_theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/) hook, so you can change this if you want.

In this example, I am activating the WooCommerce plugin:

```
function activate_mytheme_required_plugins() {
    if (!is_plugin_active('woocommerce/woocommerce.php')) {
        activate_plugin('woocommerce/woocommerce.php');
    }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'activate_mytheme_required_plugins');
```

Answer (score -1):

Write This Code On theme Function.php

```
function run_activate_plugin( $plugin ) {
$current = get_option( 'active_plugins' );
$plugin = plugin_basename( trim( $plugin ) );

     if ( !in_array( $plugin, $current ) ) {
         $current[] = $plugin;
          sort( $current );
          do_action( 'activate_plugin', trim( $plugin ) );
          update_option( 'active_plugins', $current );
          do_action( 'activate_' . trim( $plugin ) );
          do_action( 'activated_plugin', trim( $plugin) );
       }

    return null;
 }
run_activate_plugin( 'plugin-folder-name/plugin-main-file.php' );
```

It's working

Comment: Can you explain a little as how it answers the OP in addition to the code posted ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vivek, and welcome to WPSE. Echoing what @bravokeyl said, if you could explain your code that would be fantastic. Code only answers are hard to understand and in the end don't actually teach people _how_ to code :) There's an edit link below your post. Thanks!

Comment: only you can put this code in functions.php and replace plugin-folder-name with your plugin name and plugin-main-file.php with main plugin file name(index.php or plugin-file.php)